# JSON array is not created properly for my scenario in json.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I want to create a json string using json.net in C#. But the json array is not created as I expected. Here is my code:

```
  markInfo[] MarkUpdate1=new markInfo[2];
            string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { MarkUpdate =MarkUpdate1 }, Formatting.Indented);
            return jsonString;

public class markInfo
        {
            List<string> FinalMarks = new List<string>();
            List<string> EvalMarks = new List<string>();
        }
```

My expected output is :

```
{
    "MarkUpdate":[
        {
        "FinalMarks":[
            {
            }
         ]  
        },
        {               
        "EvalMarks":[
            {

            }
            ]
    }
    ]
}
```

But it generated the following output :

```
{
  "MarkUpdate": [
    null,
    null
  ]
}
```

Comment: FWIW, your "expected output" is invalid JSON. (It's fine *conceptually*, it's just got the syntax wrong. All of your property names must be in double quotes, not single quotes, not no quotes.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : yes you are correct...i will update my questions...

Comment: @Saravanan: Do you want arrays with one empty object in each, or do you really want empty arrays?

Comment: @ArjanEinbu:Acutally this is not a final json string.I am building base now.So,now "MarkUpdate" is an array that containing two elements named as "FinalMarks" and "EvalMarks"(Both are also an array).Then later i can add the values of both elements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating an anonymous type which has a `MarkUpdate` property which is assigned the value of your array which contains no object instances.

Are you trying to output one instance of a `MarkUpdate`? in which case remove your array, instantiate your markInfo class and serialize that.

You should also make your `FinalMarks` and `EvalMarks` properties, they are also not marked as public.

```
string jsonString = 
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new MarkInfo(), Formatting.Indented);
return jsonString;

public class MarkInfo
{  
    private List<string> finalMarks;
    private List<string> evalMarks;

    public List<string> FinalMarks
    { 
       get { return this.finalMarks ?? (this.finalMarks = new List<string>()); }
       set { this.finalMarks = value; }        
    }

    public List<string> EvalMarks
    { 
       get { return this.evalMarks ?? (this.evalMarks = new List<string>()); }
       set { this.evalMarks = value; }        
    }
}
```

Comment: This is your output json                                               {
  "MarkUpdate": {
    "FinalMarks": [],
    "EvalMarks": []
  }
} can you do it something like my above requirement?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

> `markInfo[] MarkUpdate1=new markInfo[2];`

...creates an array of `markInfo` but doesn't create the instances; both of the array *slots* are empty. So at the least you need to create them:

```
markInfo[] MarkUpdate1=new markInfo[2];
markInfo[0] = new markInfo();
markInfo[1] = new markInfo();
```

That still won't give you your "expected output", though, because your expected output only has a single entry, but your code is defining two entries.